# in Google App Script how do i RETURN data from one function to the calling function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to learn Google App Scrips and it has a RETURN Command which is supposed to allow you to return data from a called FUNCTION to the calling FUNCTION.  I must be doing something wrong but what?

```js
   var statPass = true
   var goodLoad = false
   for(theRow=27;theRow<35;theRow++){

     loadStatvalues(theRow,goodLoad)

     if(goodLoad==false){
       friendly.getRange(theRow,1).setValue("FAILED");
       statPass=false
     } 
   }

   function loadStatvalues(theRow,goodLoad){;
      goodLoad=true
      // ...
      if(statValue==""){goodLoad=false;return goodLoad}
      // ...  
      return(goodLoad)  // also tried "return goodLoad"
   }
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried placing the return value in parentheses, defining the value that is being returned, and reading a lot of docs.   Unfortunately while not new to programming I am very new to Google App Script (as well as javascripts).

Comment: `variable = loadStatvalues(...)` will save the returned value in `variable`.

Comment: How are you setting `statValue`? Is there anything asynchronous involved?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters to javascript functions are passed by value, unless its an object or an array (arrays are actually objects).  Parameters passed by value are numbers, strings, boolean value.

Here is an example of passing parameters to a function and returning a value.  Note only one variable can be returned, but you can return an array or an object.  Using an array or an object you can return more than one value.

```
function foo() {
  try {
    let a = 1;  // a value
    let b = [2,3,4];  // an array
    let c = {name: "Joe"};  // an object
    let d = bar(a,b,c);
    console.log("a= "+a+" notice didn't change");
    console.log("b= "+b+" notice second value changed");
    console.log("c= "+c.name+" notice name changed");
    console.log("d= "+d+" returned value from function");
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

function bar(x,y,z) {
  try {
    x = x+1;
    y[1] = 5;
    z.name = "Tom";
    return x;
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}


7:33:00 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:33:01 AM  Info    a= 1 notice didn't change
7:33:01 AM  Info    b= 2,5,4 notice second value changed
7:33:01 AM  Info    c= Tom notice name changed
7:33:01 AM  Info    d= 2 returned value from function
7:33:00 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```